# stuck at command "sbt compile" in docker ubuntu

Tags: scala, ubuntu, docker, sbt

I try to include sbt into docker images. However, it never works and always stuck at `Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.7 ...` Also, it is also not working for changing the sbt version.

Here is the snippet of docker file

FROM ubuntu:14.04

```
RUN echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install sbt //also I used force--yes
```

also, I try to install it on the container manually by using

```
wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.5.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i sbt-0.13.5.deb
```

When I run `sbt compile`, it also stuck trying to get `Getting org.scala-sbt ...`

but it is working for `sbt --version`

Basically, I dont know why sbt stucks trying to get `Getting org.scala-sbt ...`

Comment: You should have a look at this Dockerfile https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/lukasz/docker-scala/dockerfile/ the last command is `sbt --version`

Comment: What if you try to get the library it is trying to get from your host computer, does it work? That sounds like a networking issue.

Comment: You're dockerfile doesn't even run on my machine:
`E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.` with `Docker version 1.6.1, build 97cd073`

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Java Virtual Machine for SBT and so I think it's a good think you start from the `java` official docker image. Here is a basic docker file that uses the official ubuntu installation method:

```
FROM java
RUN echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
RUN apt-key update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install sbt
```

NOTE: `--force-yes` has to be there because it is not an authenticated package. I tried adding `RUN apt-key update`, but that didn't make a difference so you can omit this line.

Then, build a test image: `docker build -t test/sbt .`, create an interactive container `docker run -i -t test/sbt sbt` and play with it.

This works for me, but I noticed the download times were slow for launching SBT, so be patient at this step.

This is because the SBT executable in itself is really light and will fetch a bunch of libraries on the first run to accomplish its task. It's also a way for SBT to support multiple projects using multiple SBT versions. If you are stuck at libraries resolution, check your networking configuration. For SBT errors, they are mostly printed on the command line, but you can [configure logging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Logging.html) if you want.

What's left for you to figure out is to add your project files and issue a `compile` command to test it.

Comment: I dont think that ia the issue. I already installed java 7 and network is fine.

Comment: I think your question is not clear in the first place. Try the commands I provided in the answer and post the result, that way we can get forward. Otherwise, change your question. I think I provided most of the answers to your sub questions.

Comment: I already tried force yes before your answer, it is stucking to get sbt .... I also edited my question. For your docker one, I can start docker container in daemon mode and then use docker exec /bin/bash to connect it. but I dont think that is related to my question. I will just change my question to ask why it is stucking to get sbt make my question simpler

Comment: For the sake of other readers, the original question had a few questions that my answer try to address, but they got removed.

Answer (score 1):

sbt will try to download a higher version of itself if the project require a higher version than the currently installed sbt version. Usually there is a {projectFolder}/project/build.properties which specifies the desired sbt version for a sbt project. for example: `sbt.version=0.13.7` requires version 0.13.7

You seem to get stuck at `Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.7 ...`. But I believe sbt is actually trying to download sbt 0.13.7 to your local. As the package is not small, depending on your network speed, it may take a while.

It is also likely that there is a network connectivity issue that prevents sbt from downloading its package. So you can try to verify first your network connectivity is not a problem.

If your network is fine, another approach you can try is to go to sbt site to download 0.13.7 package manually to your docker and install it there by following instructions you can find from sbt site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it took ca. 5 minutes for ```sbt``` to get past ```Getting org.scala-sbt ...```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sbt stuck when downloading files. You can periodically check size ~/.ivy2 folder and if size isn't grow kick sbt process and rerun sbt.

For me only after 5 kicks sbt download all files!!!